# PHP PDO SQlite single query to find result with only one occurence

Tags: php, sqlite

For example, I have the following table:

```
 id  Name - Target 
 1    A       B     
 2    C       D      
 3    E       D
```

I actually have over 2 million records.

My goal is to query "Target" for "D", and return "D" data only if there is a single record of "D", in my example the query must fail because there are 2 records of "Target" with value of "D".

I tried to use count records and check if the returning query has more than one hit, but is very slow.

Is there a better approach ?

Thank you

Comment: you can use DISTINCT TARGET or can group by column by Target

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT id, name, target FROM tablename WHERE target = ? GROUP BY target HAVING count(*) = 1
```

Will return a single result or empty

Comment: Thank you, this works, however I think I may have approached it wrongly, I will submit a new question, perhaps you may help there.